# Interacting with database in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

When using MVC 4 Razor (I am new to web development), I get concerned about my understanding of interactions between the database and the client. Much like all appilications these days, there is a lot of data that is presented to the user and in different fashions. I have looked around, and I can't find a concrete C# example, as they're mostly PHP.

Below is an example of loading data into a jQuery DataTables plugin.

- Is this the correct way of formatting data to JSON  and loading it into a jQuery function?
- If I wanted to update/delete/insert to the database from the client, is there a way to do that within JavaScript, or should I be doing it within C# somehow? (I have looked around and really, there isn't a ton of documentation)

Note: If it is easier to answer my question without concerning the use of jQuery DataTables, that's completely fine. I'm looking for a broader spectrum of information.

**HTML**

```
<table id="grid" class="row-border hover order-column " width="100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sequence</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Ticker #</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Bonus</th>
            <th>Allocation</th>
            <th>Begin Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div id="pager"></div>
```

**Home Controller - C#**

```
    public string GetAssociateFromDb()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEFCOMP"].ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connString;
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FUND", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                myAdapter.Fill(dt);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
            }
        }
      }
```

**In the _Layout**

```
<head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../../Content/jQueryDataTables1.10.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src= "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: You're forgetting about the **M** in MVC. Put your data into a model, and pass that to a view. You don't have to use JSON and jQuery to put your data into the table.

Comment: »You don't have to use JSON and jQuery to put your data into the table« When you to the rendering via ASP.Net MVC you are right, But when you are using `datatables.net` jQuery is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, since I've been on the ASP-Road, but I hope to provide you some help:

1) Read the Documentation of DataTables, especially the paragraph about [Ajax source data](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html). There you learn how to use Datatables with server generated data.
[Serverside processing](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) might be of interest too.

2) You are free to use a html-skeleton (as you did), but you could use [Custom Column Definitions](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

3) In order to get the Datatables Plugin to work you need a) an Element in your DOM, where the Datatable can hook on: `$('#example').dataTable()` does that; and b) you need data to display.

There are two basic formats:

I) You have loose data, which is represented as an `Array` of `Arrays`.
Each `Array` representing a Row, which consists of an `Array` of columns as in [this](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html) or [this](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) example.

II) You have structured data, which comes as `JSON` as in [this](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) example

So when I get your example right:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

does exactly that.

What your code is lacking is the initialization of the datatable (see *(3)* ). And then you are done.

P.S.:
Perhaps [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) is interesting for you.

Edit: 
I forgot to address this point

> If I wanted to update/delete/insert to the database from the client, is there a way to do that within JavaScript, or should I be doing it within C# somehow? (I have looked around and really, there isn't a ton of documentation)

No. *Within* Javascript there is no way. But it is possible to send a message to the server, which lets the server know, that you wanted to delete one entry. It is possible to intercept the rendering process of `datatables.net`, so that you generate attributes, which you could use to identify the objects displayed in the column (e.g. an ID or the like). And you could then initiate a `DELETE` request to the server

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/endpoint'+idOfSelectedElement,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.delete) for the documentation.

Edit2: A question to elaborate a bit more on the topic

> When dealing with insert, update, delete, select etc from the front end to server, is this always done with ajax? Is it safe? Is it fast? How are the requests usually formatted to delete specific rows, or update specific rows? (your answer doesn't have to be jquery datatables specific) Thanks!

**a) CRUD and ajax**

There is no clear answer to that: *it depends*. If you are working with browsers as clients of your interface/API, there are only two of the many `HTTP-Methods` implemented, namely `GET` and `POST`. This is, what we all know from our standard `<form>` specified under `method`. These were the genuine methods available (rooted in historical decisions, but I see no reason to stick with that; browser developer should change this constraint).

In order to use a *restish* API, which has e.g. also support of `PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH` there is a way to circumvent this constraint. Many frameworks provide parsing a hidden `<input>`-field where the "rest-method" is defined and map to the according controller.

As you can see, it is not always necessary to do it *asynchronous* or with *javascript*. So *ajax* is only one - but a nice one - option to play with. Unless not otherwise restricted (managers, users etc.) I would always go for *ajax*.

**b) Is ajax safe**

It is as safe as you make it. There are possibilities for securing your endpoints. But as I said, I am not quite up to date, what Microsoft offers, there are possibilities for sure.

**c) Is it fast**

It is as fast as your *hardware* (connection, server etc.) allow. 
There is no difference in terms of performance doing something like a `PostBack` or a `$.post()`. The main difference is, that a traditional `POST` is a) not asynchronous and b) you are loosing the current context.

**d) Form of CRUD requests**

You form your actions via `URL` and `HTTP-Verbs`:

1) Get a list of all Users: `GET` *api/users*

2) Get information about user 1: `GET` *api/users/1*

3) Get all users, which are from Seattle `GET` *api/users?location=Seattle*

4) Get all male users, which are form Seattle `GET` *api/users?location=Seatte&gender=male*

5) Create a user `POST` *api/users/* sending a JSON representation of the created user {"name":"Doe", "firstname":"John","city":"Seattle" ...}

6) Update user 1 `PATCH`/`PUT` *api/users/1* sending JSON of the changes {"city":"Miami"} (if he moved to Miami}

7) Delete user 1 `DELETE` *api/users/1*

If you want to specify the output data from the server, you could set the `ACCEPT` field in the header e.g. to `application/json` or `application/xml`.

As you see, there is a big advantage in using a RESTish API: you have a set of universal verbs, which each service speaks, which is easy to learn and to adapt.

These are the basics of the *REST*-philosophy. There is more to say, but not in this post ;)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, Thomas. This is the kind of answer I was hoping to receive. I did look at the documentation - at least 25 times. I think my lack of extensive JS knowledge is a contributing factor to my confusion. Can I ask you a question that extends from the 2nd half of your answer? When dealing with insert, update, delete, select etc from the front end to server, is this always done with ajax? Is it safe? Is it fast? How are the requests usually formatted to delete specific rows, or update specific rows? (your answer doesn't have to be jquery datatables specific) Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I elaborated a bit further on the topic: Hope this helps you a bit, getting grips on JSON, REST and the like. Feel free to ask more questions (in other posts): I am glad, if I can help you out.

Comment: To be honest, all of my confusion originated when I started looking at AngularJS and it's MVC-oriented nature. The CRUD requests are **definitely** something I need to learn and become very familiar with. They also contribute to my confusion. Let me ask 1 more thing => in your examples: `api/users` is this using EF/ORM? I don't use EF/ORM currently. Am I making a call to a method that has a SQL statement? (as above?)

Comment: »in your examples: api/users is this using EF/ORM? I don't use EF/ORM currently. Am I making a call to a method that has a SQL statement? (as above?) « No. These are the API calls, or so to say: This is, what the server/Framework gets. These are the `routes` you have to define somewhere. This is independent from EntityFramework. You only neet something, that binds incoming JSON to C# objects - which IMHO does ASP.Net MVC for you.

Comment: Sounds like something I'll need to take a closer look at and keep practicing. Thank you for the knowledge! I'm sure I'll be back with more.

Answer (score 2):

I really feel bad about recommending this, but based on what you're doing you should investigate the use of [Webforms in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms).

Webforms are the most straightforward way to provide easy CRUD operations on a database in C# while exposing the operations safely to the user. You also will work entirely with C# and the ASP.NET elements in html, so there's no need to manually use javascript with most basic tasks.

If you want to get more advanced then you can go with [MVC5 in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5) but that doesn't have the same level of builtin controls, data table displays, and similar that webforms has baked into itself. MVC5 does give you more power and flexibility in return, but if you need to get something done in a hurry or in a very basic form then you'll probably be fine with Webforms.

The problem with webforms, and why I feel bad recommending it, is that it tends to not encourage good [N-Tier design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384398.aspx) because it both allows you to do things like embed SQL queries in your views (which is blasphemy) and a lot of the examples display exactly that behavior.

It is possible to setup a good distribution of responsibilities into multiple tiers with webforms, which is what I'm doing at my current job, but it doesn't do a great job of encouraging good design. That being said, it does encourage getting things done in a hurry, so that can sometimes outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: I see no sense in recommending webforms. This has nothing to do with webforms. And webforms are no advantage to his approach. So why recommending it? And disencouraging of Javascript is ridiculous.

Comment: "Note: If it is easier to answer my question without concerning the use of jQuery DataTables, that's completely fine." << OP requested other alternatives to jQuery which is why I provided one.

Comment: How are webforms easier than `datatables.net`?

Comment: You don't have to go through an intermediate JSON layer and you can bind the results of a SQL query directly to a gridview or template or whatever you need to display the data. Removing the JSON layer removes complexity since you're going to have to implement the data loading either way, whether it's for binding to the gridview or serializing to JSON for dumping out of a webservice to use in datatables. Even if you ignore the reduced complexity, webforms are easier for a beginner because the documentation and abundance of examples is superior to his current less-documented approach.

Comment: »webforms are easier for a beginner because the documentation and abundance of examples is superior to his current less-documented approach« I think we stop arguing at this point. This is personal belief not fact based.

Comment: @KennethPosey I appreciate you taking time to look through my code and answer my question. MVC was not 'my' choice - it is my company's new standard. MVC is a little confusing to me, as to why I tried to express my 'low' level of experience. While time is always a factor, I would rather learn MVC and do what everyone else is doing these days (JS frameworks, libraries, JSON, etc.) because it is relevant. I hope that makes sense. As for MVC 5, we are stuck on VS 2010 for the time being. However I am trying to get VS 2013 on my home pc. I'll take a look at your links! Thanks again!

Comment: Do not get me wrong: although I strongly advocate the REST-approach, there is nothing wrong in using WebForms. You could argue about the unnecessary level of abstraction, which is build in WebForms to shield the developer from the different medium (Web/Desktop). But that was not in question. WebForms have their place (I am sure of). But on the other hand it is unwise, when the company hops on the trend du jour without thinking about the developers or the benefits of one approach over the other,

Comment: @Mark MVC is the superior route to take if you have the development experience to back it up. Webforms is targeted for people with less experience which is why I brought it up, but if you're "stuck" with MVC then that's far from a bad thing, and you don't even need to upgrade from 4 to 5 immediately. That being said, upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013 *is* completely worthwhile and important to do because VS2013 is amazing. Study carefully the information I posted about NTier and that should help you get up to speed with the "layer" approach MVC uses.

Comment: @KennethPosey Certainly! All information is valuable information. Just curious, how did *you* learn MVC? Practice? Trial and error? Books? School/Courses? As a developer, I of course know the best route is documentation + trying things out for yourself. I am simply curious because I am the only developer on my team beginning MVC. Everything else is WebForms/WinForms. So I see this general concept of MVC and I am easily confused on what is a correct approach vs incorrect.

Comment: @Mark Documentation + trying things out myself + working with people with more experience and asking lots of questions. MVC is pretty straightforward to tackle if you have a basic understanding of web development. The only hard part is remembering how the pieces fit together and that comes with time. MVC is basically webforms without the built in controls and with better distribution of responsibilities. Build a basic website with some basic views, models and controllers, then move onto partial views, then move onto outputting JSON for jQuery consumption. That should get you 90% of the way.

Comment: @KennethPosey Awesome. Thank you for the insight and for your answer. I really do appreciate it.